# FullCalendar or MOment inputting wrong timezone

Tags: fullcalendar, momentjs

I'm using fullcalendar (https://fullcalendar.io/) 
Here is my code:

```
  $.ajax({
        url: '/BackOffice/AllCalendarApp',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                editable: false,
                lang: 'pt',
                navLinks: true,
                events: data,
                eventAfterRender: function (event, element) {                        
                    $(element).tooltip({                           
                        title: event.title,
                        container: "body"
                    });
                }
                });
        }
    })
```

On my controller im passing the time right, and im receiving the dates right on    "events: data". However when the callendar gets displayed on the view it appears with -1 hour. 
No idea whats causing this since im getting the data correctly in the ajax call.

Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try setting `timezone: "local",`

Comment: That worked ! 
Thanks.